# android - working with broadcastReceiver on android ICS (version 4)

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i'm having a problem on android ICS (version 4) and broadcastReceiver . please help:

i'm trying to listen to a simple intent of network connectivity change . i've tried the next tutorial (with the broadcastReceiver defined in the manifest alone - the first part of the website ) :
http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1526/
on ICS , it doesn't capture any intent , and on any other version it works just fine .

can anyone please tell me what's wrong? do i need to add a new intent filter other than the one that listens to CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ?
has google blocked listening to such intents on ICS ? are there any other new rules for ICS that have changed ?

i think that other broadcastReceivers also won't work on ICS using the manifest .

Comment: Umm.. You might be missing few things. Post some code, manifest, and perhaps logs as well.

Comment: @ Kumar Bibek : the code is on the link . please read it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample code shown in that link may work, but it needs an activity. On Android 3.1+, an application is installed in a "stopped" state. While in that state, no `BroadcastReceiver` will work, until the user manually launches an activity from the application. The application will return to this "stopped" state if the user force-stops the application from Settings.

So, add an activity to your project, launch it once, and then see if your receiver works.

Comment: do you have any reference to read this info from?
also , why did they do it? it's breaking the way many application might work . is it for security ? are there any BroadcastReceivers that still listen without installations ? what about bootup intents?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "do you have any reference to read this info from?" http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols "are there any BroadcastReceivers that still listen without installations ? what about bootup intents?" no and no.

Comment: oops , i meant "without running" . is it still correct? i've heard of applications that once your device is stolen , you can choose to install them using the market , and then it will tell you the position of the device and even allow you to erase the data of it . does it mean that now such applications won't be able to work (unless the thief opens them) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: " does it mean that now such applications won't be able to work (unless the thief opens them) ?" -- correct.

Comment: thank you for all of your answers. i wonder why google decided to remove such features , even if the user specifically wanted to install an app that starts without the need to open it . i really liked the idea that even if an android device would be stolen (or just not found) you will always be able to find it . is there any way to overcome such an obstacle for such applications , or are they doomed?

Comment: I have the same query , how will I be able to know whether my phone is connected on VPN ?